# Streaming a movie from Windows (Media Center??) to A500

Tags: video, streaming, 3.2-honeycomb

Simple straight question: I own an Acer Iconia Tab A500 w/3.2 OS and a Windows 7 PC with lots of movies, including H.264 HD in Matroska format.

How can I stream that content, supposed that I installed K-Lite Codec Pack, on Android by installing the least possible amount of software? The tablet is already shipped with Acer ClearFi which is a DLNA implementation and looks compatible with Windows Media Center, however when I tried to play a non-HD movie in MPEG-4 format the default player reported that the fortmat is unsupported.

I'm new and a bit confused to Android video and home streaming. I don't know how codecs work in the Linux-like world.

[EDIT] About codecs (if these matter): on Windows, I can watch the videos with Windows Media Player too, not only VLC/MPC
I remember that once I was able to stream to my Xbox 360 with Vuze's embedded media server with live transcoding. Do I need something like that for streaming to Android too?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use TVersity to stream to my Android device, Logitech Revue, Original Xbox, Xbox 360, etc. TVersity can transcode the video on the fly.

I have, in the past, been able to get Matroska container files to play, but not always and with varying results. Sometime they don't play at all, sometime they played fine, and sometimes they play, but the video is choppy and out of sync with the audio.

Being able to stream the video to your android device will depend on the video codec used to encode the video. If the device does not support the codec, it will not play. AFAIK, android, out of the box, does not support the matroska container, actually, there are a lot of formats that android does not support. Using something like TVersity on your "Media Server" allows you to transcode these videos in a format that the device will understand, and can play.

Comment: Very helpful answer. I have been able to set up TVersity and I'm able to play videos by browsing TVersity via browser. Not much like the Xbox 360 experience but the files are actually being transcoded on the fly. Any ideas on using ClearFi could be appreciated. ClearFi provides a very simple and intuitive interface

Comment: TVersity is a DLNA server, so if ClearFi is a DLNA client it should pick up TVserity as a server.

Comment: ClearFi is DLNA compliant, but I found that while ClearFi detects the server (after properly REconfiguring firewall) it finds no content. I'm looking into it

Answer (score 0):

I personally like [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp) to stream my media, and they have [apps for all major mobile device platforms](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/apps.jsp).  It does on the fly transcoding to FLV.